# CollectionViewSource in windows metro app

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, collectionviewsource

I have a collection, for which i require 3 different views
1. All data of collection
2. Grouped data  (grouping criteria will be modified during application lifecycle  )
3. Filtered data (filter criteria will be modified during application lifecycle)

What i want is that all views should bind to same collection so that any change to collection should be synced to all the views.

With WPF, this can be achieved using [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx).
In Modern UI apps, [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource) still exists, but with limited capabilities. It does not have SortDescription and FilterDescription.

How to achieve collection sync in Modern UI apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you are asked to perform your sorting, grouping, and filtering with LINQ in WinRT.  The `CollectionViewSource` *appears* to only provide a common view to be shared between controls.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/winappswithcsharp/thread/599432f6-0e28-45de-a4e0-1f105afd081d)

Comment: LINQ is fine, problem is sync'ing. When i add item in Collection, it is not reflected in other controls, for which CollectionViewSource.Source is set to the collection