# Metro App CollectionViewSource ObservableCollection Filter

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

It appears that filtering an `ObservableCollection` with `CollectionViewSource` is not possible in **WinRT**:

[See here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582919/collectionviewsource-in-windows-metro-app)

I can filter using **LINQ**, but how do I get the **UI** to update if changes that affect the filtered data are made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up writing my own class to achieve the desired effect:

```
public class ObservableCollectionView<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> _view;
    private Predicate<T> _filter;

    public ObservableCollectionView(IComparer<T> comparer)
        : base(comparer)
    {

    }

    public ObservableCollectionView(IComparer<T> comparer, IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(comparer, collection)
    {

    }

    public ObservableCollectionView(IComparer<T> comparer, IEnumerable<T> collection, Predicate<T> filter)
        : base(comparer, collection == null ? new T[] { } : collection)
    {
        if (filter != null)
        {
            _filter = filter;

            if (collection == null)
                _view = new ObservableCollection<T>(comparer);
            else
                _view = new ObservableCollection<T>(comparer, collection);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<T> View
    {
        get
        { 
            return (_filter == null ? this : _view);
        }
    }

    public Predicate<T> Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return _filter;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                _filter = null;
                _view = new ObservableCollection<T>(Comparer);
            }
            else
            {
                _filter = value;
                Fill();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Fill()
    {
        _view = new ObservableCollection<T>(Comparer);
        foreach (T item in this)
        {
            if (Filter(item))
                View.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private int this[T item]
    {
        get
        {
            int foundIndex = -1;
            for (int index = 0; index < View.Count; index++)
            {
                if (View[index].Equals(item))
                {
                    foundIndex = index;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return foundIndex;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);

        if (_filter != null)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    foreach (T item in e.NewItems)
                        if (Filter(item))
                            View.Add(item);
                    break;

                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:

                    break;

                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    foreach (T item in e.OldItems)
                        if (Filter(item))
                            View.Remove(item);
                    break;

                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                    for (int index = 0; index < e.OldItems.Count; index++)
                    {
                        T item = (T)e.OldItems[index];
                        if (Filter(item))
                        {
                            int foundIndex = this[item];
                            if (foundIndex != -1)
                                View[foundIndex] = (T)e.NewItems[index];
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    Fill();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);

        if (_filter != null)
        {
    // TODO: Implement code for property changes
        }
    }
}
```

Not yet perfect. So improvements/suggestions welcomed.

You can now bind this object, directly to a control using the View property.

Comment: not perfect... YET! can you show an simple usage example? It would be better to understand this class purpose/advantages.

Comment: Purpose: A sortable and filtered ObservableCollection. Create an instance of this object, use as you would normally use an ObservableCollection. Has a filter property in the form of a Predicate, so you can filter the data. Then when binding to a control, bind to the View property. that's it!

Comment: Nice solution.  I am going to use this in my project for the time being!

Comment: I don't understand the presence of the constructor overloads that take `IComparer<T>` arguments. These overloads don't exist in `ObservableCollection<T>`, so a) they don't seem to be needed in this view implementation, and b) the above won't compile, because the `base` calls aren't valid (the overload doesn't exist in the base class).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the filtering changes are observable, so you can set the source of the `CollectionViewSource` to an `ObservableCollection` and make the changes on that collection or assign a new `Source` of the CVS to a new, filtered collection.

Comment: I have a source ObservableCollection, which I filter and returns IEnumerable. Then I pass this to the constructor of an ObservableCollection and assign to CollectionViewSource. Updates happen against the source ObservableCollection. Now their is a disconnect between the source and filtered collections, so changes to the source are not picked up by the filter. How do I overcome this?

Comment: You need to filter and assign it again. Alternatively update the filtered collection when you update the original one.

Comment: I have... see my answer below.