# ObservableCollection to 1 of 3 listviews depending on some property

Tags: c#, listview, visual-studio-2013, binding, windows-store-apps

I currently have an ObservableCollection named `MyList` that is binded to the itemsource of on listview. It also adds and removes items from MyList.

What I want is to add items in each listview based on some criteria. More specific, If the property `Status` is "Yes" the item should go to the first listview `MyListview`, if it is "No" to go to the second listview `MySecondListview` and `If Status==""` and the property `Date` which is a DateTime property points today, then it goes to the third listview.

My MainPage code is:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyList = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = MyList;
        }
         private void Add_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyList.Add(new MyClass("Yes", new DateTime(2015, 5, 4)));
        }

        private void Delete_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyList.Remove((MyClass)MyListview.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

My XAML for Main Page is:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App17.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App17"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Viewbox>

        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="768" Width="1366">
            <Button x:Name="Delete" Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="116" Margin="376,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Click="Delete_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="Add" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="116" Margin="111,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214" Click="Add_Click"/>
            <ListView x:Name="MyListview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="497" Margin="71,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="349" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
            <ListView x:Name="MySecondListview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="497" Margin="468,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="317"/>
            <ListView x:Name="MyThirdListview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="497" Margin="893,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="317"/>

        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Page>
```

My Class code is:

```
class MyClass 
{ 
    public string Status { get; set; } 
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public MyClass(string status, DateTime date) 
    {
        Status = status;
        Date = date; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: In our previous discussion, I had suggested looking at the `CollectionViewSource` class, to obtain appropriate `ICollectionView` objects for use in binding your single list object to each `ListView`. Have you taken a look at that? Did you try using it? It would be helpful to understand what you've attempted already in terms of addressing this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh. So, I didn't realize this but it turns out that Winrt (i.e. Windows Store apps) does not support filtering in `ICollectionView`. It seems like every time I turn around, I find another XAML/WPF feature that was inexplicably omitted from Winrt, and this is one of them.

So, while this would have been trivial to accomplish in WPF (just create a `CollectionViewSource` object, subscribe to the `Filter` event, and bind to the object's `View`), this turns out to be a bit more of a hassle in Winrt.

There are already some related articles, including one on Stack Overflow that provide alternatives. For example:

- Stack Overflow: [Metro App CollectionViewSource ObservableCollection Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16251559/)
- [A WinRT CollectionView class with Filtering and Sorting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So)

That second one is a very elaborate implementation to support filtering and other operations. It's overkill for your purposes, but you may find in the future you would like to use features it includes.

The first example, while more appropriate in scale to your question, approached the problem in somewhat different way than I would. In particular, it implements a single `ObservableCollection<T>` subclass that in turn has a single view. This prevents it from being useful for the "one collection, many views" scenario.

So I wrote an `ObservableCollection<T>` that is in the same vein, but which itself is the view, and references an independent instance of `ObservableCollection<T>`. You can use as many instances of this class, which I called `FilteredObservableCollection<T>`, as you need while still maintaining a single source collection. Each view will update itself as needed, according to the filter, when the source collection changes.

**<caveat index="0">**
In this approach (the original inspiration for my class, as well as my own), the bound view is itself an `ObservableCollection<T>`. And in particular, this is *not* a read-only collection. It's very important that any consumers of these "view" objects not try to directly modify the view object, even though they can. They should only ever *display* the object.

The second link above is better in this respect, as it's implementing an actual `ICollectionView` interface, which addresses the mutability question. Frankly, it would be better from a code maintenance point of view to do it that way, to make it clearer what object is the real list, and what objects are just the views.

But fact is, this way is a *lot* simpler and easier to implement. Just be careful using it, and you won't get hurt. :)
**</caveat>**

**<caveat index="1">**
The other very important limitation to understand is that this implementation will *not* update the viewed collection on changes to the filter logic (i.e. in case you pass a `Predicate<T>` that itself depends on some mutable state somewhere), or on changes to the displayed data (i.e. if a property being checked by the filter is modified in one or more displayed data items).

These limitations could be addressed in a variety of ways, but to do so would significantly increase the complexity of this answer. I would like to try to keep things simple. It's my hope that merely pointing these limitations out is sufficient, to ensure that if you do run into a situation where you need a more reactive view implementation, you're aware of the limitation and know you'll have to extend this solution to support your need.
**</caveat>**

That class winds up looking like this:

```
public class FilteredObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private Predicate<T> _filter;

    public FilteredObservableCollection(ObservableCollection<T> source, Predicate<T> filter)
        : base(source.Where(item => filter(item)))
    {
        source.CollectionChanged += source_CollectionChanged;
        _filter = filter;
    }

    private void _Fill(ObservableCollection<T> source)
    {
        Clear();
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            if (_filter(item))
            {
                Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private int this[T item]
    {
        get
        {
            int foundIndex = -1;
            for (int index = 0; index < Count; index++)
            {
                if (this[index].Equals(item))
                {
                    foundIndex = index;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return foundIndex;
        }
    }

    private void source_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> source = (ObservableCollection<T>)sender;

        switch (e.Action)
        {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            foreach (T item in e.NewItems)
            {
                if (_filter(item))
                {
                    Add(item);
                }
            }
            break;

        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
            // Without a lot more work maintaining the view state, it would be just as hard
            // to figure out where the moved item should go, as it would be to just regenerate
            // the whole view. So just do the latter.
            _Fill(source);
            break;

        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            foreach (T item in e.OldItems)
            {
                // Don't bother looking for the item if it was filtered out
                if (_filter(item))
                {
                    Remove(item);
                }
            }
            break;

        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
            for (int index = 0; index < e.OldItems.Count; index++)
            {
                T item = (T)e.OldItems[index];
                if (_filter(item))
                {
                    int foundIndex = this[item];

                    if (foundIndex == -1)
                    {
                        // i.e. should never happen
                        throw new Exception("internal state failure. object not present, even though it should be.");
                    }

                    T newItem = (T)e.NewItems[index];

                    if (_filter(newItem))
                    {
                        this[foundIndex] = newItem;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RemoveAt(foundIndex);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // The item being replaced wasn't in the filtered
                    // set of data. Rather than do the work to figure out
                    // where the new item should go, just repopulate the
                    // whole list. (Same reasoning as for Move event).
                    _Fill(source);
                }
            }
            break;

        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            _Fill(source);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So, with that helper object implemented, setting up your UI is simple. Just create a new instance of the above class for each view of your data you want, and bind to that instance.

For this example, I reworked your original UI fairly extensively, to clean things up a bit and make it easier to observe what's going on. I added buttons to create items that should appear in each view, and there are now four views: the whole list (where you can select and delete items), and then one each for the three filtering options.

With this approach, the `DataContext` winds up being `this` instead of the one list, because we want access to the individual views. The members also need to be changed to public properties, so that the XAML binding engine can find them. This example assumes that they will be initialized once and never changed; if you want the bindings to be updatable, you'll want to make these dependency properties or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `MainPage` class.

I also added a `DataTemplate` for your class, so that the presentation of each item in each list was useful (i.e. something other than the type name).

With all that, the XAML winds up looking like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestSO30038588ICollectionView.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestSO30038588ICollectionView"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

  <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myClassTemplate">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Page.Resources>
  <Viewbox>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="768" Width="1366">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Button x:Name="Delete" Content="Delete"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Height="116" Width="224"
              Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
              Click="Delete_Click"/>
      <Button x:Name="Toggle" Content="Toggle Yes/No"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Height="116" Width="224"
              Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
              Click="Toggle_Click"/>
      <Button x:Name="AddYes" Content="Add Yes"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Height="116" Width="214"
              Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
              Click="AddYes_Click"/>
      <Button x:Name="AddNo" Content="Add No"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Height="116" Width="214"
              Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
              Click="AddNo_Click"/>
      <Button x:Name="AddEmpty" Content="Add Empty"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Height="116" Width="214"
              Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"
              Click="AddEmpty_Click"/>
      <ListView x:Name="AllElementsList"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myClassTemplate}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>
      <ListView x:Name="MyListview"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myClassTemplate}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding yesList}"/>
      <ListView x:Name="MySecondListview"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myClassTemplate}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding noList}"/>
      <ListView x:Name="MyThirdListview"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myClassTemplate}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding emptyList}"/>
    </Grid>
  </Viewbox>
</Page>
```

And the `MainPage` code looks like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyList { get; set; }
    public FilteredObservableCollection<MyClass> yesList { get; set; }
    public FilteredObservableCollection<MyClass> noList { get; set; }
    public FilteredObservableCollection<MyClass> emptyList { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        MyList = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
        yesList = new FilteredObservableCollection<MyClass>(MyList, item => item.Status == "Yes");
        noList = new FilteredObservableCollection<MyClass>(MyList, item => item.Status == "No");
        emptyList = new FilteredObservableCollection<MyClass>(MyList, item => item.Status == "" && item.Date.Date == DateTime.Now.Date);

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void AddYes_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyList.Add(new MyClass("Yes", DateTime.Now));
    }

    private void AddNo_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyList.Add(new MyClass("No", DateTime.Now));
    }

    private void AddEmpty_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyList.Add(new MyClass("", DateTime.Now));
    }

    private void Delete_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyList.Remove((MyClass)AllElementsList.SelectedItem);
    }

    private void Toggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass oldItem = (MyClass)AllElementsList.SelectedItem,
            newItem = new MyClass(oldItem.Status == "Yes" ? "No" : (oldItem.Status == "No" ? "Yes" : ""), oldItem.Date);

        MyList[AllElementsList.SelectedIndex] = newItem;
    }
}
```

With the above, changes are only ever made directly to the `MyList` object. The state of this list is shown in the first `ListView` object on the page (i.e. the left-most one). The three different buttons add items that are configured to be filtered differently. The items are added to the main list, but then the three filtered views update themselves automatically to reflect those changes, and you will see that in the other `ListView` objects on the page (each one is below the button that adds an item that is displayed in that `ListView`).

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:**

Some additional points that were in comments and which I think could improve the usefulness of this answer:

- Deleting items from each `ListView` (i.e. the `SelectedItem` in a given `ListView`) can be done easily, as long as you still just delete from the actual `MyList` collection; the object references in each list are your original objects, so even though they may be selected in one particular view, you can always delete that object from `MyList`
- You can modify the individual `MyClass` objects but, without additional work in this example, the filtering won't change. I.e. if MyClass correctly implements binding features (either dependency properties or INotifyPropertyChanged), changes to an item's properties will be shown on-screen, but won't affect filtering. The above example requires an object to be replaced in `MyList` with a different instance having the new values for it to be refiltered.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! :D It works Perfectly!! Also it was very detailed and clean code!!

Answer (score 0):

From a MVVM perspective you would have either 3 ObservableCollections in which each one represents each listview. But the "model" would have a unified list. As suggested in the comments to properly do this with one ObservableCollection would require creating a view (at least to use bindings.) 
I would say that the most obvious solution is often the least confusing to read.

```
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyFirstListCollection...
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MySecondListCollection...
```

it is generally better to the best of your ability to separate the logic for your view from your view-model. That would make it much easier to isolate issues to one or the other. The more you couple them with direct manipulation of the listviews on the screen the harder it is to see what is going on.
Then in XAML you could just bind to them

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding MyFirstListCollection}"... (rest of the margin stuff)
```

The add event handler can now just add to the desired observable collection allowing the bindings to do the updating of the view.

As a note you can also assign any arbitrary object as a DataContext, while in production this isn't the best practice you can do:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

The ObservableCollections then have to be "properties" and not just data members but adding a getter and setter is trivial
For example if you start with a view model that looks like (i am leaving out a lot of code for simplicity like the lack of creating the Observable collections in the ctor):

```
class ViewModel
{
    MyModel model;
    ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyFirstList { get; set; }
    ObservableCollection<MyClass> MySecondList  {   get; set;   }
    ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyThirdList { get; set; }     
    public ViewModel(MyModel model) {
         this.model = model;
         RefreshCollections();
    }

    public void RefreshCollections() {
         //Clear the observable collections.
         MyFirstList.Clear();
         foreach(var item in model.MyUnifiedList) {
              //TODO: add to the correct collection based on criteria.
         }
    }
}
```

I would then attach your data context to this class. of course supplying a model in which to work from. the "new MyModel()" could instead be a reading of a file or what not.

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModel(new MyModel())
```

Lastly your class would look like.

```
class MyModel {
     List<MyClass> MyUnifiedList;
}
```

You may want to use some kind of event to cause a UI refresh. But in some senses I think your critera of a single list is complicating the problem. I would personally have 3 lists all the way down. Just because they are the same object does not mean they need to be in the same list. No need to over optimize, trust me you wont regret it.
Of course when you need to change something you would be refreshing everything.
Generally you want to consider MVVM such that your View Presents the Information in the View Model and the Model implements the logic. to actually do the work. (When reasonable) this isn't a hard a fast rule but some reading on MVVM will help to distiguish between these places. there is a ton of ways to allow the model to refresh the view model.

Comment: If I understood correctly your solution is to make 3 collections? 1 for each listview? the thing is that day by day the item's properties might change, so I would have to move the items from each collection to another one, which is not so great. I talked with @Peter Duniho last night on my previous post and he told me to use the CollectionViewSource class. So I tried doing this today but I had no luck making progress.

Comment: The solution in my opinion would be to create a Model and store the items there and to cause a refresh or "move" in the collections above. So If you instead had a List<MyModels> in which you then read into a split into 3 ObservableCollections you could then "refresh" each collection to move them. But what is wrong with removing an item from the ObservableCollection? that is why they are there. It is no different than moving from one list view to another except isn't tying together the view and view model, If need be I can add some code

Comment: Ye If you could add some code about how  would I make this Viewmodel and how I would connect the collections

Comment: Connecting the collections is simply adding the ItemSource="{Binding nameofCollection}" You may need to search for some WPF guides. as bindings are pretty critical. The goal isn't to give you an copy paste answer but help you get the idea of WPF bindings.

Comment: Check out this post for links to some good guides for WPF/MVVM [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)

Comment: Ok so how can I add items ton one of the lists now via the button Add?

Comment: @user2975038 It seems you prefer the other answer but to add to any of the lists you would need to save the view model as a variable, but then it becomes `code`(viewmodel.MyFirstList.Add(...)) the view is updated automatically. Generally I feel that the single list requirement is a bit excessive and really using one list unless you have a really good reason. Using filtering to present 3 views is hiding your code implementation and makes it so that when you update on of the collections all 3 views needs to be updated instead of the one that was bound.

Comment: I do it so that I can then store all this info somewhere, easier.